# How to create module/controller of NestJs in a mono-repo with Nx?

Tags: nestjs, nomachine-nx

I'm trying to use the Nx monorepo approach.
I've created a project with Angular & NestJs:

```
npx create-nx-workspace --preset=angular-nest
```

But now I'm trying to create modules.
On a standalone NestJs project, I would usually do something like:

```
nest g module auth
```

But if I do it in the root the file doesn't get created in the correct folder. What is the expected approach to develop in such multi-repo environment? should I open each app subfolder in a dedicated VS code? But then I guess I would loose the benefit of shared libraries?

I also think I could move my VS Code terminal in the correct folder, but then each time I open a new one I should go into the correct folder, pretty sure it will leads me to some errors.

THanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're in an Nx workspace, you should be using the nx generator instead of the nest generator.

```sh
nx g @nrwl/nest:module auth
nx g @nrwl/nest:controller auth
```

I believe the generator will ask for which project as well. There's also the [Nx Console Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nrwl.angular-console) for VSCode where you can see the changes before committing to any of them.